# How do i add an image to the background of nav on shopify

Tags: shopify

I am really unfamiliar with liquid on  Shopify, I cannot seem to find where to put the image in behind the navigation bar. And I can't seem to find any documentation. Using the template Debut- it's for a client. Can someone possibly direct me in the right direction- Also is there a special code for this.

Comment: Liquid is a HTML server side template language. Any front end implementation is done via proper HTML itself. Start here - https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid

Comment: What do you mean by "behind the navigation bar?" Are you saying a background image on the navigation bar?

Comment: Also, welcome to SO and please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to ask a question on SO that will give you the best chance of getting the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could gather from your question, it sounds like you're asking how to add a background image to the navigation bar.

In the debut theme you can use CSS to select the desktop navigation bar with the `.site-header` class. Then you can simply add a background image to it:

```
.site-header {
  background-image: url('image-url.com/image.png');
}
```

If you want the client to be able to change this image you'll have to do it in the actual .liquid file using `<style>` tags:

```
<style>
  .site-header {
    background-image: url('{{ section.image_variable_id | file_url: 'master' }}');
  }
</style>
```

The file is Sections -> header.liquid. From there you'll have to figure out how to use sections to pull in an image from the client, and use it on the page. Here are some resources for you to take a look at:

- https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/sections
- https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema